# Cannot install sqlite3-1.3.6 ruby gem in windows xp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, sqlite

New to Ruby on Rails.  Working in Windows XP.

I have installed the rails installer from railsinstaller dot org

Working through the example  from guides dot rubyonrails dot org / getting_started

Issued the command 'rails new blog'

the bundle install fails on Network error while fetching https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/sqlite3-1.3.6.gemspec.rz

I have downloaded the sqlite3-1.3.6 gem and tried to manually install, receiving the following error:

checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Install SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

I've read many different websites that tell me to make sure Sqlite3.dll is in the system path, so I've downloaded the latest Sqlite3.dll (from sqlite3 dot org, using the windows precompiled binaries) and placed them within the path, even overwriting the Sqlite3.dll file within c:\Railsinstall\Ruby1.9.3\bin but all to no avail.  I've even tried registering Sqlite3.dll using regsrv32 Sqlite3.dll, only to receive the message "Sqlite3.dll was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found.  This file can not be registered"

I have successfully been able to install Sqlite3-1.3.6-x86-mingw32.gem, however 'rails new blog' still looks for Sqlite-1.3.6

If I try 'rails new blog --skip-bundle', I can successfully create blog, but I think I'm just skirting the issue.

Anyone have any idea what I might be missing?  I have the Sqlite3.dll within the path, but still can't get past the Sqlite3.h file not found error.

Thanks

(I know I may have a proxy issue, but I still should be able to install the gem file locally.  I've been able to do that for every other requested gem file.)

Comment: Try to remove your `Gemfile.lock` and then run `bundle check`. Show us the output.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to [SQLite3 download page](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html), “Precompiled Binaries For Windows” section
2. Download “sqlite-shell” and “sqlite-dll” archive files
3. Unpack them in C:\WINDOWS\system32 folder (or any other that is in your PATH)
4. Install the sqlite3 Ruby gem.

Having .dlls in system32 is **MANDATORY**

Comment: My apologies, thought I'd receive an email about posts, and didn't see one.....  I did try placing those files along my PATH  (Including one attempt at placing them in System32).  No Dice.  Finally installed cntlm which got me around my proxy issue.  Once I did this, the sqlite3 ruby gem installed correctly.  I did not redo the placement of SQLite3 dlls before using cntlm.